# Upper and lower bound on integral

Tags: integration

Consider the following integral

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^n)^M \,d x$$

It converges to $0$ as $M\to\infty$, but I would like to find bounds on the convergence rates. What I mean is that it is straightforward to find constants A and B such that

$$\frac{A}{M}<\int_0^1 (1-x^n)^M \,d x<\frac{B}{M^{1/n}}$$

However, is it possible to obtain identical upper and lower bounds? The claim that I have is that the lower bound can also be made of the form $A'/M^{1/n}$, but I have not been able to prove it.

Comment: Where you wrote "as $m\to\infty$", did you mean "as $M\to\infty$"?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Would a closed solution also be fine?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by closed solution. I could expand by the binomial formula and integrate term by term, but I am not able to figure out the leading term in the resulting expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $n \gt 1$,

If we set $I_{M} = \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^n)^M dx$, then, I believe we get, using integration by parts ($u = x$, $v = (1-x^n)^M$) that

$$I_{M+1} = \int_{0}^{1} (M+1)n x^n (1-x^n)^M dx$$

and so

$$ (M+1)n I_{M} - I_{M+1} = (M+1)n \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^n)^{M+1} dx = (M+1)nI_{M+1}$$

$$I_{M+1} = \frac{(M+1)n}{(M+1)n +1}I_{M} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{(M+1)n + 1}\right) I_m$$

Now we can use the estimate $1 - \frac{1}{x} = e^{-x + O(x^2)}$ and get an estimate for $I_{M}$.

All we would need is an estimate for $\sum_{k=0}^{M} \frac{1}{kn+1}$ which I believe is $\frac{\log M}{n} + O(\frac{1}{M})$ and thus your integral is

$$\Theta\left(\frac{1}{M^{1/n}}\right)$$

(Assuming I have done the calculations right).

Answer (score 2):

We start with some expressions for the beta function,
$$
B(p,q) = 2 \int_0^1 x^{2p-1} (1-x^2)^{q-1} \,dx = \frac{\Gamma(p) \Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}
$$
(see e.g. equation (21) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)), where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.  Setting $p=\frac{1}{n}$ and $q=M+1$, multiplying by $\frac{1}{n}$, and using the identity $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$ we get
$$
\frac{2}{n} \int_0^1 x^{\frac{2}{n}-1} (1-x^2)^{M} \,dx = \frac{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(1+1/n)}{\Gamma(M+1+1/n)}.
$$
Making the substitution $x = u^{n/2}$ in the integral gives your integral on the left-hand side.  That is,
$$
\int_0^1 (1-u^n)^M \,du = \frac{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(1+1/n)}{\Gamma(M+1+1/n)}.
$$
The right-hand side can be rewritten as
$$
I_M=\frac{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(1+1/n)}{\;\Gamma(M+1+1/n)}=\frac{M! \; (1/n)! }{(M+1/n)!}=
\binom{M+1/n}{M}^{-1}.
$$
So why is that? Let's start with exanding $(1-x^n)^M$. We get
$$
I_M=\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^M (-1)^k \binom{M}{k} x^{nk} dx= \sum_{k=0}^M (-1)^k \frac{\binom{M}{k}}{nk+1}. $$
The last sum may be recognized as [Binomial Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) $T$ of the sequence $\{ \frac{1}{nk+1} \}$. Since $TT=1$, we transform the result to
$$
T(I_M)=\sum_{k=0}^M (-1)^k \frac{\binom{M}{k}}{\binom{k+1/n}{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^M (-1)^k \frac{M!\frac{1}{n}!}{(M-k)!(k+\frac{1}{n})!},
$$
which [gives](http://tinyurl.com/7354adz) $\displaystyle T(I_M)= \frac{1}{Mn+1}$.

The heavy use of WolframAlpha makes me believe, that what I showed is not enough.
Answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111643/19341) would give me better feeling.

Maybe this could help there: The last sum could be rewritten using [Pochhammer Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) as
$$
T(I_M)=\sum_{k=0}^M  \frac{(M-1)_{k}(1)_k}{(\frac{1}{n})^{(k)}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^M  \frac{(M-1)_{k}(1)_k}{(\frac{1}{n}+k-1)_{(k)}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
$$
and if $M\to \infty$ we get $T(I_M)= _2F_1(1,(M-1);\frac{1}{n}+k-1;1)$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is unable to evaluate this. Can you show we get that? +1 in anticipation.

Comment: But it did, so you say it wrong?

Comment: No, I am not saying it is wrong. All I was requesting was to expand on it a bit more!

Comment: @Aryabhata I expanded as far as I could (for now ;-)!

Comment: @draks: I have edited your comment to include a derivation of your first equality, but I don't yet have free edit privileges so a mod will need to approve it before it posts.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Cool thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After evaluating your integral as a beta function as in the beginning of draks' post, you can use Stirling's approximation for the gamma funcion to find an asymptotic series (for another approach see [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-1/issue-1/The-asymptotic-expansion-of-a-ratio-of-gamma-functions/pjm/1102613160.full)).  Truncating at the third term gives

$$\int_0^1 (1-u^n)^M \,du = \frac{\Gamma(1+1/n)}{M^{1/n}}\left\{1 - \frac{n+1}{2n^2M} + O\left(\frac{1}{M^2}\right)\right\} \hspace{1cm} (M \to \infty).$$