# Question on Inverse Pochhammer Symbol

Tags: special-functions, binomial-coefficients

I struggled quite a while without success, so I highly appreciate if
anybody can help me, proving [that](http://tinyurl.com/76xb73q):
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1+1/n \right)^{(M)}}=\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(M-k)!(nk+1)},
$$
where $(1+1/n)^{(M)}$ is the [rising factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol), with $    x^{(n)}=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}$.

A correct answer would help [answering](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110153/19341) this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110135/19341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Antonio Vargas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5531/antonio-vargas) helped a lot in answering this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110135/19341), I will just briefly give a summary.

First multiply with $M!$ and recognize the Beta Function (see e.g. equation (21) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html))

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{M!}{\left(1+1/n \right)^{(M)}}&=&\frac{\Gamma(M+1)\Gamma(1+1/n)}{\Gamma(M+1+1/n)} \\
&=&\frac{2}{n} \int_0^1 x^{\frac{2}{n}-1} (1-x^2)^{M} \,dx\\
&=&\int_0^1 (1-u^n)^M \,du \,\,(\text{ substitute } x = u^{n/2})\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^M(-1)^k \frac{ M!}{k!(M-k)!(nk+1)}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$