# Computing $\int_0^\infty\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}\mathrm dx $

Tags: analysis, integration, improper-integrals, partial-fractions

I would like to compute:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}\mathrm dx $$ $$ n\geq 2$$

So my question is how can I find the partial fraction expansion of

$$\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}\ ?$$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**HINT**: Here's a trick to find partial fraction expansions. Compute

$$\lim_{x\to -k} \frac{(x+k)}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)} \; .$$

This should give you the coefficient of the term $1/(x+k)$ in the expansion.

**EDIT**: As Américo points out, the partial fraction expansion is

$$\frac{1}{\left( x+1\right) \left( x+2\right) \cdots \left( x+n\right) }
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\left( n-k\right) !}\cdot\frac{1}{x+k} \; .
$$

The indefinite integral of that expansion is

$$\ln\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)^{\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\left( n-k\right) !}} \right) \; .$$

When you fill in the upper bound, you can see that the result must be zero as the leading power in $x$ for the product is $0$ because

$$0 = (1-1)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k} (n-1)!}{(k)!\left( (n-1)-k\right) !} = (n-1)! \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\left( n-k\right) !} \; .$$

Therefore, we are left with the lower bound

$$-\ln\left( \prod_{k=1}^{n}(k)^{\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\left( n-k\right) !}} \right) \; .$$

For $n=2,3$ and $4$ you get resp. $\ln 2$, $\ln(2/\sqrt{3})$ and $\ln(2^5/3^3)/6$.

The lower bound can also be written as

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} {n-1 \choose k} \ln(1+k) \; .$$

Comment: Somehow I've never seen this trick before - very clever! (This doesn't work so well unless all terms are inverse-linear, but it's going straight into my toolbox...)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 14):

If $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)\dots(x+n)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{A_i}{x+i}$$

To compute $A_k$, multiply by $(x+k)$ and set $x = -k$.

In fact, this can be used to show, that for any polynomial $P(x)$ with distinct roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots \alpha_n$, that

$$\frac{1}{P(x)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{P'(\alpha_j)(x-\alpha_j)}$$

where $P'(x)$ is the derivative of $P(x)$.

Answer (score 8):

Based on my computations in SWP for $2\leq n\leq 8$ I *conjecture* the
following expansion

$$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\left( x+1\right) \left( x+2\right) \cdots \left( x+n\right) }
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\left( n-k\right) !}\cdot\frac{1}{x+k}.
\end{equation*}$$

*Added*. How to prove or disprove? Induction doesn't seem easy.

*Added 2*. It follows from Aryabhata's answer. See comment below.

Comment: From my answer, you can see that the coefficient is $\frac{1}{(1-k)(2-k)\dots((k-1)-k)(k+1-k)\dots(n-k)} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$

Comment: @Aryabhata: Many thanks! The first coefficient is positive. Shouldn't it be $\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$, for $k=1,2,\dots n$?

Comment: Yes, it is $(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: So now we have to find $$ \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\ln(1+\frac{a}{k})$$

Comment: @Chon: Actually, the part with the limit to infinity is $0$. It's the lower bound that gives something interesting. I've computed the first few values for $n=2,3$ and $4$ and they are resp. $\ln 2$, $\ln(2/\sqrt{3})$ and $\ln(2/\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: +1 and: Funny, I think I just had a quite similiar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/111643/19341) recently.

Comment: I made a mistake, for $n=4$ the result should be $\ln(2^5/3^3)/6$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&I_{n} \equiv\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over
\pars{x + 1}\pars{x + 2}\ldots\pars{x + n}}} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}^{\,\large\overline{n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over
\Gamma\pars{x + 1 + n}/\Gamma\pars{x + 1}} =
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\pars{x + 1}\Gamma\pars{n} \over
\Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\ 
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}t^{x}\pars{1 - t}^{n - 1}\,\dd t}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n - 1}\
\overbrace{\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x}\,\dd x}}^{\ds{-\,{1 \over \ln\pars{t}}}}\
\dd t =
-\,{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - t}^{n - 1} \over \ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] \stackrel{t\ =\ \expo{-z}}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-z}\pars{1 - \expo{-z}}^{n - 1} \over z}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
\phantom{-}{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{z}\expo{-z}\pars{1 - \expo{-z}}^{n - 1}\,\dd z
\\[2mm] &
-{1 \over \pars{n - 2}!}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{z}\expo{-2z}\pars{1 - \expo{-z}}^{n - 2}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\phantom{-}{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{n - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{z}\expo{-\pars{k + 1}z}\,\dd z
\\[2mm] &
-{1 \over \pars{n - 2}!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2}{n - 2 \choose k}
\pars{-1}^{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{z}\expo{-\pars{k + 2}z}
\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
-{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}
{n - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{\ln\pars{k + 1} \over k + 1}
\\[2mm] &
+ {1 \over \pars{n - 2}!}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2}{n - 2 \choose k}
\pars{-1}^{k}\,{\ln\pars{k + 2} \over k + 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{n - 1 \choose k - 1}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{\ln\pars{k} \over k}
+ {1 \over \pars{n - 2}!}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{n - 2 \choose k - 2}
\pars{-1}^{k}\,{\ln\pars{k} \over k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{\large\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\mathcal{I}_{nk}\ln\pars{k}}\\ &
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}_{nk} \equiv
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k\pars{n - k}!}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{k - 1}!} +
{1 \over \pars{k - 2}!}} =
\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{\large{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{n - k}!\pars{k - 1}!}}\\
\end{equation}

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{I_{2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\ln\pars{2}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{I_{3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 2}\ln\pars{3}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{I_{4}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{3} + {1 \over 6}\ln\pars{4}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{I_{5}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 6}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 4}\ln\pars{3} + {1 \over 6}\ln\pars{4} -
{1 \over 24}\ln\pars{5}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{I_{6}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 24}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 12}\ln\pars{3} + {1 \over 12}\ln\pars{4} -
{1 \over 24}\ln\pars{5} + {1 \over 120}\ln\pars{6}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{I_{7}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 120}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 48}\ln\pars{3} + {1 \over 36}\ln\pars{4} -
{1 \over 48}\ln\pars{5} + {1 \over 120}\ln\pars{6} -
{1 \over 720}\ln\pars{7}}
\\
\ds{\vdots} & \ds{=} & \ds{\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots\quad\vdots}
\end{array}\right.
$$